# Websphere Sample RESTFull Application

Tags: websphere, sample, websphere-7

I am looking for sample RESTFull application, that can be deployed in Webpshere Application Server 7.x.

Posting here with great hope after exhaustive search. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A RESTFull application from a WebSphere perspective is an application deployed in WebSphere Application Server (WAS) that can respond to "REST" requests.  IBM's WebSphere Application Server implements the JAX-RS APIs to easily declare a Java class as exposed through REST requests.

If one does a quick google on the phrase "websphere jax-rs" in the first page of results one will find a large list of samples, examples and tutorials.  Working through any of those samples should result in what you are looking for.

See for example:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/topic/com.ibm.webservice.samptut.doc/topics/jaxrstut/jaxrs_abstract.html
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrcS5HA7fUo